# SDL_LockTexture() returning an unexpected pitch value

Tags: android, textures, sdl, sdl-2, yuv

I'm displaying the Android Camera preview on a native app, using SDL2.0.7 (Nexus 5, armeabi-v7a, ndk 16.1).

I'm using the **N21** YUV image format and I was expecting that, creating an `SDL_Texture` of that format, the *pitch* value returned by `SDL_LockTexture()` would be greater than what I'm getting right now.

Sample code:

```
SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_NV21, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, 720, 480);
int res = SDL_LockTexture(texture, nullptr, &pixels, &pitch);
```

**I was expecting to get a pitch value of `720 * 12 / 8`, i.e. `1080`**, where `720` is the width of one row, `12` is the number of bits for a single YUV N21 pixel and `8` is the number of bits in one byte, because [the SDL2 documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockTexture) states that:

> pitch: this is filled in with the pitch of the locked pixels; the pitch is the length of one row in bytes

Now, **the value of pitch actually returned by the function call is `720`**. The fact is that, if I use that `720` value, the camera preview will be displayed with an unnatural green predominance, while if I disregard the `720` pitch and use my expected `1080` pitch, the camera preview is good (and the app runs smoothly, too).

Is there something wrong in my assumptions (e.g. that the number of bits for a N21 pixel is 12, as the Android's `ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel()` suggests)? Am I using the SDL library in a wrong manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The create texture utility for a streaming texture does this internally:

```
// ...

if (texture->access == SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING) {
    size_t size;
    data->pitch = texture->w * SDL_BYTESPERPIXEL(texture->format);
    size = texture->h * data->pitch;
    if (data->yuv) {
        /* Need to add size for the U and V planes */
        size += 2 * ((texture->h + 1) / 2) * ((data->pitch + 1) / 2);
    }
    if (data->nv12) {
        /* Need to add size for the U/V plane */
        size += 2 * ((texture->h + 1) / 2) * ((data->pitch + 1) / 2);
    }
    data->pixel_data = SDL_calloc(1, size);
    if (!data->pixel_data) {
        SDL_free(data);
        return SDL_OutOfMemory();
    }
}

// ...
```

In your case, for you are using `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_NV21`, `yuv` is false and `nv12` is true (try it with a debugger if it sounds strange).
It means that the allocated size isn't `pitch * height`. Instead it's:

```
(pitch * height) + 2 * ((height + 1) / 2) * ((pitch + 1) / 2);
```

Where `pitch` is equal to `width` in this case.

At the end of the day, it's 1.5 times the size of the image, that is 12 bits per pixel.

---

It's granted that the value of `pitch` is somehow *wrong*, for it's equal to `width`.
Actually, because of the allocated space, it should be probably 1.5 times the width of the image as you were expecting.
However I'm not that sure about that, for I'm not such an expert of SDL2.